# Не выполняется код при пустом JSON (AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, json

Здравствуйте.

```
        success: function(data) {
            alert(1); // Выполняется
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            // Если ответ пустой, то ничего не выводит.
            if(!json.length) {
                alert("Test");
            }
            alert(1);
        }
```

В случае, если приходит пустой ответ, то, код дальше не выполняется, то есть, все, что следует после переменной. Как решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: if(json.length > 0)
В джаваскрипте не так как в пхп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ответ пустой, то json = null, поэтому

```
if (json===null) {
   // code
}
```

Если вы не уверены, что получаете верный JSON:

```
try {
  json = $.parseJSON('{')
} catch (e) {
  json = null;
  // вывод сообщения об ошибке
}

// остальная логика
```

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, выдает SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data, если json пуст, как быть?

Comment: @Fishy, используйте обработку ошибок.